# onPause not fired when home button is pressed

Tags: android, onpause, android-homebutton

I have an Android `AppCompatActivity` that fails to fire `onPause` event when the Home button is pressed.  According to the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#onpause):

```
The system calls this method as the first indication that the user is leaving your activity (though it does not always mean the activity is being destroyed);
```

However, whenever I am in the AppCompatActivity, onPause does not fire when Home button is pressed.  Otherwise it fires as expected for back button or normal close of the AppCompatActivity.

I have rebooted the test device with status quo.

I am handling the event as such:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
   super.onPause();
   Log.d(TAG, "onPause - Test");
}
```

The following event fires with the Home button:

```
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint()
{
    Log.d(TAG,"onUserLeaveHint - Test");

}
```

However, I cannot do anything but log to console, all other actions are ignored.

**Edit**

I think this is related.  When I do press the Home button, the following exception is thrown:

```
WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{7d162a0 u0 com.test.myapp/com.test.myapp.TestActivity}
```

Which is what happens when an ANR forced kill is executed

Comment: Can you verify, that if you place a breakpoint on `super.onPause()` line, then the debugger does not stop there?

Comment: @azizbekian - Verified

Comment: Is the keyboard opened when you press home button?

Comment: @azizbekian - No keyboard open.

Comment: @AndroidAddict Are you pressing home key to view `recent apps` ? I am asking because some Manufacturers do that.

Comment: @Sagar No, just tapping to get back to the home screen - no long press.

Comment: @Android Addict do you have any flags set for this Activity in your manifest?

Comment: @Sagar No flags, just a label and theme.